# Sharepoint Migrating On Premise Event Receiver to Remote Event Receiver Online Office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

We had earlier developed an event receiver for On Premise 2013 Sharepoint Site.
Now the requirement is to migrate that event receiver to Sharepoint Office 365 as a Remote Event Receiver.
After complete migration of code using (spsite = properties.Site) and web object is giving error

```
'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers.SPRemoteEventProperties' does not contain a definition for 'web' and no extension method 'web' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers.SPRemoteEventProperties' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Cant we use SP objects on Remote Event Receiver.
if not what is a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use only client side API in remote receivers. Mainly below namespaces

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.EventReceivers;
```

Then you can follow the pattern of first creating the context object and then loading followed by executeQuery.